# ClearCase: Can I hijack a file in dynamic view?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I am working in a dynamic view in Unix platform. I need to hijack a file temporarily and cancel the hijacking later. But the command `chmod +w filename` is not working.
I get the message `chmod: WARNING: can't change filename`.
I can change the read-only attribute of the file from a snapshot view in windows.

Questions:

1. Is hijacking possible in a dynamic view? If yes, how?
2. Is there a cleartool command to cancel hijacking of a file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the side-effects of a dynamic view is that ClearCase will control the attributes of the file you access to through the network, as opposed of a snapshot view (where everything is copied on your hard drive).

1/ Yes it is possible, even though it isn't really an "hijacked" state.
The dynamic equivalent is named "eclipsed": the idea is for a private file of the same name than a versioned one to take the place ("eclipsing") of the versioned file.

You simply make a copy of that file as a backup, and make that file invisible by not selecting it (type "`cleartool edcs`" anywhere within the dynamic view):

```
element /vob/path/to/file -none
```

Then you rename the backup copy, restoring its original name.

[image: eclipsed file]

2/ to undo an eclipsed file, you simply move it or delete it.
The versionned file (eclipsed by the private one) is restored instantly.

See IBM article "[About eclipsed files and ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21132484)" for more.

Comment: I tried this in a UCM view and couldn't get it to work. Is there a way to do this in a UCM view?

Comment: @Jozef Sure as long as it is a dynamic view, and that you put that rule *before* the one selecting the LATEST from the branch associated to the UCM stream.

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing an unreserved checkout?

`cleartool checkout -unreserved filename`

Comment: `cleartool: Error: To operate on UCM branch, must be set to an activity and a UCM view.`

Comment: buddy. In UCM each view is associated with an activity. If you see the properties of view , you can see whether any activity is associated with it or not. If there is no activity is associated then you can't checkout/checkin. His command is useful.