# Error on Login Page

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, cleartool

I have made some changes in couple of files and checked in into the View of the cleartool and performed build activity. The build was successful and we have deployed the generated ears on Weblogic server. But after the deployment the some part of the code from two jsp files are populated on login screen. The file repository is very big that I am unable to identify where is the error.

As the build is successful, I am unable to understand why is the code populated on the login screen weirdly. I like to know whether the build gets successful even though there are jsp errors and in which circumstances we find any code displayed in such a way weirdly or whether the files i have checked in are not properly **checked in**.

Comment: JSP files aren't compiled when you build an .ear so you won't see errors until you actually deploy

Answer (score 1):

If you know the files involved, you can go to their parent folder in the view you are using to modify them, and do a:

```
cleartool ls
```

That will give you their status.
Pay attention to a status like hijacked (in a snapshot view) or "[eclipsed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7799307/6309)" (in a dynamic view). In that case, the changes wouldn't be properly checked in.

For each file, you also can display their version tree:

```
cleartool lsvtree -graph aFile
```

Comment: If a file is not properly checkedin do they affect the build and do we have these weird circumstances to be faced?

Comment: @user1879683 it can affect the build is said build is done elsewhere, with another view which wouldn't reflect the last modifications.

Comment: I have tried the command bash-3.00$ cleartool lsvtree -graph login.jsp but it gives me this error
bash-3.00$ Error: Can't open display:

Comment: VonC could you please help me with cleartool in Unix. I am a little confused in hijacked (in a snapshot view) or "eclipsed" (in a dynamic view).

Comment: @user1879683 the idea remains the same on Unix (except dynamic views are in `/views/vobs/aVob/...`).