# How to create an engineering activity in Rational Clearcase Explorer?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I get the next error when I am trying to checkin/checkout in clearcase:

```
cleartool: Error: To operate on UCM branch, must be set to an activity and a UCM view.
```

Well as I can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7799040/1305193) this happens because there is no activity attached to the view I used. My question is how I can create an engineering activity and associate it with an existing view using Rational Clearcase Explorer.

I need it in order to have an ability to checkin/checkout files using clearcase console.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a [`cleartool mkact`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkactivity.htm):

```
cd /pat/to/your/UCM/view
cleartool mkact aNewAct
```

That will create *and set* a new activity to your current view.

Any checkout/checkin after that will use that curent activity.

---

For Clearquest-enabled projects, see "[About creating UCM activities in a project enabled for Rational ClearQuest](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_about_cr_ucmact_cq.htm)":

> **You do not create UCM activity objects directly.**
>
> In a project that is enabled for Rational® ClearQuest®, an activity usually refers to two objects that are linked together:
>
> - a UCM activity object and
> - a record in a Rational ClearQuest user database whose record type is enabled for UCM.
>
> The process of creating an activity in a project that is enabled for Rational ClearQuest entails the creation of two objects in a specific order:
>
> 1. You create records (based on a record type that is enabled for UCM) in a Rational ClearQuest user database.
>
>    - On Windows®, you can create records from the Rational ClearQuest client or, if policy permits, from Rational ClearCase® windows (Check Out, Check In, or Add to Source Control).
>    - On UNIX®, you can create records only from the Rational ClearQuest client.
> 2. When you set an activity in a view (which you can do by clicking **`Actions > WorkOn`** for a Rational ClearQuest user database record), the following occurs:
>
>    - An activity object is created in the stream to which the view is attached.
>    - The activity object is linked to the record in the Rational ClearQuest user database whose record type is enabled for UCM.
>        The name of the Rational ClearCase activity is set to match the Rational ClearQuest record's ID.

Comment: I tried it and I got the next error: cleartool:  Error: The "mkactivity" command can not be used in a stream which is
contained in a ClearQuest-enabled project. To create an activity in this
stream, use the "setactivity" command in one of the stream's views and
specify a ClearQuest record identifier as the argument. This will cause an
activity to be automatically created which is associated with the indicated
ClearQuest record.

Comment: @AntonKasyanchuk ok, I have added the relevant help section for ClearQuest-enabled projects. See my edited answer. What version of ClearCase and ClearQuest are you using, by the way?