# convert clearcase eclipsed file to a checkout

Tags: clearcase

So the joyful sys admins like to lock down the vob between 9p-7a for backups... why, one can only speculate and loose hours of productivity.... oh wait that is happening anyways since the vob is locked for ... 10 hrs... anyways I digress.

So I recently started using dynamic views and have been pleasantly surprised at how useful it has been with constant integration. But with my old snapshot views when the vob was locked I could always hijack a file and convert it to a check out later, but that is not allowed in a dynamic view so following the following post:
 [ClearCase: Can I hijack a file in dynamic view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798915/clearcase-can-i-hijack-a-file-in-dynamic-view)
I've managed to 'hijack' or eclipse said files to continue working, but now comes the question... what is the easiest way to convert said eclipsed files to checkouts?

In a snapshot view with a hijack you simply pass the '-usehijack' flag to the co command, but how do you do this with a eclipsed file.

I can remove the file and get the original version back, but then I'd lose my changes.

The only way I can think of is to move the file elsewhere, let clearcase replace the file, then checkout and copy the file back, but is that the only way?

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- rename the file
- checkout the original file (no longer eclipsed)
- overwrite the checked out file with your copy.

A bit cumbersome, but scriptable.

Comment: Thanks. Another function to add to my bashrc :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a little while, and I don't have ClearCase access anymore, but I think that a 'cleartool co -nodata' might do the trick for you.

Comment: I don't see any mention of '-nodata' associated with the co command. I did find a '-ndata' but that checks out the file and essentially blanks it out. Thanks for the suggestion.